# Why do I get "Module 'x' not found", when building iOS App in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods

My Flutter App builds perfectly fine in VS Code, but when I try to build the app in Xcode to publish it to the AppStore, it gives me the Error:

> Module 'connectivity' not found

I'm not familiar with native iOS development, Cocoapods and Xcode. Has someone an Idea what the problem could be?

Thank you for your answer/input

Here is a screenshot of my Xcode:
[image: This is my Xcode]